# Is there any significant difference in how easily they can be implemented with a recursive descent parser?

Tags: compilers

What is the distinction between S-attributed definitions and L-attributed definitions? Which one is more expressive? Is there any significant difference in how easily they can be implemented with a recursive descent parser? Why or why not?